# Pass Multi Column Array to Server

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have got a page with data generated client-side that is formatted as a fifteen column array. The number of rows will vary based on user input, anywhere between 1 and 200 total. I want to pass this array to my server in an efficient manner where it will be inserted into a MySQL database using php, but I don't know how the data should be packaged for transport. The data in the page is generated using JavaScript and is laid out in this fashion:

```
<div id="row1" class="row">
  <span id="entry1">User generated data.</span>
  <span id="entry2">User generated data.</span>
  <span id="entry3">User generated data.</span>
  ...
  <span id="entry15">User generated data.</span>
</div>
<div id="row2" class="row">
  <span id="entry1">User generated data.</span>
  <span id="entry2">User generated data.</span>
  <span id="entry3">User generated data.</span>
  ...
  <span id="entry15">User generated data.</span>
</div>
```

Recommendations anyone?

Comment: How are you formatting/generating this array?

Comment: @NathanaelShermett Each row is in a <div> and each entry within each row is in a <span>.

Comment: @NathanaelShermett I have updated my question to contain a code sample.

Comment: But how are you generating this? PHP? JavaScript?

Comment: The page is generated using JavaScript.

Comment: In that case, read here: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/197159/how-do-i-pass-arrays-in-javascript-to-php-using-post-method. Then use PHP's `serialize()` and `unserialize()` to store it in the database.

Comment: You either serialize it however you like, post it, and deserialize it on the server, or post it "as an array" by giving the keys names PHP recognizes as an array "myvar[0]='some user data'" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is canon to repeat the same ID multiple times.

```
<div id="row1" class="row">
  <span id="entry1">User generated data.</span>
  <span id="entry2">User generated data.</span>
  ...
<div id="row2" class="row">
  <span id="entry1">User generated data.</span>
```

I'd use compound IDs:

```
<div id="row1" class="row">
  <span id="entry1_1">User generated data.</span>
  <span id="entry1_2">User generated data.</span>
  ...
<div id="row2" class="row">
  <span id="entry2_1">User generated data.</span>
  ...
```

At that point you can:

- build a POST query with all items as key/values:
   entry1_1=User generated data.
   ...

  which will be easily parseable by PHP, or:
- build a JSON string in Javascript as a dict of dicts
  { row1: { entry1: "User generate data" }, row2: {...}
- you might try to preparse the array for PHP by submitting fields
  like this:

  entry[1][1]=User generated data.

  ( "entry[1][1]" is the name of the key. PHP *should* parse it correctly).

You could also, depending on how you create new items, directly create a POST FORM, appending fields like this to the DOM:

```
<input type="text" name="entry[7][14]" value="" class="input" />
```

Sorry, but without a better idea of your interaction design, it is awkward to make suggestions.